# How to treat type of 'enum class Foo' property as 'enum' type?

Tags: qt, enums, qt5

I have a class with property of type `enum class Foo`

```
enum class Foo{A, B};

class Bar: public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

    Q_ENUM(Foo)

    Q_PROPERTY(Foo myCoolProperty READ myCoolProperty WRITE setMyCoolProperty)

    Foo _foo;

public:

    Bar();
    Foo myCoolProperty() const;
    void setMyCoolProperty(Foo v);
};
```

How to treat `myCoolProperty` as enum-typed property? For example next code

```
Bar *bar = new Bar();

const QMetaObject *m = bar->metaObject();
for(int i=0; i< m->propertyCount(); i++ ) {
    QMetaProperty mp = m->property(i);

    qDebug("name=%s, isEnumType=%d", mp.name(), mp.isEnumType() );
}
```

Prints:

> name=myCoolProperty, isEnumType=0

For example, if I change `enum class` to `enum`, then test code prints `isEnumType=1`. How to make `isEnumType=1` with `enum class`?

Comment: Did you try to register your scoped enum with `Q_ENUM_NS`? I ask, because your enum's scope isn't `Bar` class where you register it.

Comment: @vahancho I try to do it. Q_ENUM_NS works same.

Comment: class Foo { public: enum Foos { A, B }; }; ... void setMyCoolProperty(Foo::Foos v); ... ->setMyCoolProperty(Foo::B); ???

Comment: "if I change `enum class` to `enum`..." Really? Not for me. Which Qt?

Answer (score 0):

Moving `Foo` into `Bar` class fixes it. I don't think the `Foo` enum gets properly registered when it doesn't belong to the class with the Q_OBJECT (or Q_GADGET or Q_NAMESPACE) macro. It's still a valid property, just not of a known type. AFAIK an enum by itself can't be registered, it has to belong to some other annotated ("meta-objectified" :-) class/namespace.

*ADDED*: Just move the enum in/out of the *public* space of Bar class to see that it works with the former. The `class` specifier makes no difference. Also no difference if the `staticMetaObject` is examined vs. a "dynamic" `objectInstance->metaObject()`.

```
enum /*class*/ Foo{A, B};

class Bar: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Foo myCoolProperty READ myCoolProperty WRITE setMyCoolProperty)
  public:
    //enum /*class*/ Foo{A, B};
    Q_ENUM(Foo)

    Bar() {}
    Foo myCoolProperty() const { return _foo; }
    void setMyCoolProperty(Foo v) {}
  private:
    Foo _foo;
};

typedef Foo foo_t;
//typedef Bar::Foo foo_t;

//Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(foo_t)  // no difference

int main(int, char**)
{
  //qDebug() << qRegisterMetaType<foo_t>();  // no difference
  const QMetaEnum emeta = QMetaEnum::fromType<foo_t>();
  qDebug() << emeta.isValid() << emeta.enumName();

  const QMetaObject m = Bar::staticMetaObject;
  for(int i=m.propertyOffset(); i< m.propertyCount(); i++ ) {
    const  QMetaProperty mp = m.property(i);
    qDebug("name=%s, isEnumType=%d %d", mp.name(), mp.isEnumType(), mp.enumerator().isValid());
  }
  return 0;
}
#include "main.moc"
```

With Foo outside Bar:

```
false 
name=myCoolProperty, isEnumType=0 0
```

With Foo inside Bar:

```
true Foo
name=myCoolProperty, isEnumType=1 1
```

Comment: It's a bug. I registered QTBUG-80345 in qt bugreports.

Comment: @chabapok Why do you think it is a bug? And it has nothing to do with the `class` type, the behavior is exactly the same with a plain old "C type" enum, or one specifying the underlying data type.  The meta property system needs the enum to be contained within a Q_OBJECT/etc. Where is it documented that it should work as you expect?